# Save button failing to upload data to Parse

Tags: android, parsing

I'm having trouble getting past the basics of having my app communicate with a server to store data.

I'm attempting to use Parse (https://parse.com/) as the backend of the Android app I'm working on. I got the basic "Quick Start" Parse app going fine, and was able to upload data from the app on my phone to my Parse account using the onCreate() method. Then I tried to create an app which would upload some data when a button is pressed. I can install and run the app, but when I press the button nothing seems to happen, and when I then check my Parse account no data has been uploaded. I included the Parse libs and added them to the build path.

Here is the app code-

```
package greg.mariani.saveLoad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class SaveLoad1Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Parse.initialize(this, "private_app_token1", "private_app_token2"); 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void saveUpdates(View view) {
        ParseObject updates = new ParseObject("Updates");
        updates.put("court", "Brentwood Rec");
        updates.put("update", "Game On");
        updates.saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Here is the layout xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save" 
        android:onClick="saveUpdates"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you added internet permission to your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! I had to restart the project and forgot about this permission. Thank you.